# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Good Day!

I'm have a problem in deserializing JSON string

This is my function look like:

```
 public static void Deserialised()
    {
        string jsonString = "{\"data\":{\"merchantRefNo\":\"foo\"," +
                            "\"responseText\":\"Approved\"," +
                            "\"status\":\"A\"," +
                            "\"txnDate\":\"20220321\"," +
                            "\"txnId\":\"000067\"," +
                            "\"txnTime\":\"1049\"," +
                            "\"txnType\":\"sale\"," +
                            "\"amt\":\"109\"}," +
                            "\"dataType\":\"trans\"}";

        Root myDeserializedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString); //Error popup here!

        foreach (var datas in myDeserializedJson.data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(datas.merchantRefNo);
        }
    }
```

This is my Model:

```
 public class Data
    {
        public string merchantRefNo { get; set; }
        public string responseText { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
        public string txnDate { get; set; }
        public string txnId { get; set; }
        public string txnTime { get; set; }
        public string txnType { get; set; }
        public string amt { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public List<Data> data { get; set; }
        public string dataType { get; set; }
    }
```

Error:

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[fortestings.Program+Data]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'data.merchantRefNo', line 1, position 25.'

Comment: Data isn't a list in your JSON. Why did you make it a list in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Root` class, change the `List<Data> data` to `Data data` and then you can de-serialize your `JSON` string as required to your `Root` class:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string jsonString = "{\"data\":{\"merchantRefNo\":\"foo\"," +
            "\"responseText\":\"Approved\"," +
            "\"status\":\"A\"," +
            "\"txnDate\":\"20220321\"," +
            "\"txnId\":\"000067\"," +
            "\"txnTime\":\"1049\"," +
            "\"txnType\":\"sale\"," +
            "\"amt\":\"109\"}," +
            "\"dataType\":\"trans\"}";
        
        var result =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString);
        Console.WriteLine(result.dataType);
        Console.WriteLine(result.data.merchantRefNo);
        Console.WriteLine(result.data.status);
        Console.WriteLine(result.data.txnId);           
    }
}

public class Data
{
    public string merchantRefNo { get; set; }
    public string responseText { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string txnDate { get; set; }
    public string txnId { get; set; }
    public string txnTime { get; set; }
    public string txnType { get; set; }
    public string amt { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
    public string dataType { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
trans
foo
A
000067
```

You can find a working example here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8Nsl9m

Answer (score 0):

{
"data":{
"merchantRefNo":"foo",
"responseText":"Approved",
"status":"A",
"txnDate":"20220321",
"txnId":"000067",
"txnTime":"1049",
"txnType":"sale",
"amt":"109"
},
"dataType":"trans"
}

This is your root object JSON but you class is expecting a list of data

```
public class Root
{
    public **List<Data>** data { get; set; }
    public string dataType { get; set; }
}
```

So for deserializing json is not matching with your model.
Your Json should be like below
{
"data":[{
"merchantRefNo":"foo",
"responseText":"Approved",
"status":"A",
"txnDate":"20220321",
"txnId":"000067",
"txnTime":"1049",
"txnType":"sale",
"amt":"109"
}],
"dataType":"trans"
}

Comment: Hi. I was hoping to get the dataType in root after i correct the error.